# Why do these two html/css files work differently despite the same code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the codepen for the first one:

`Bad Pen`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGpxrp

and here's the code for the second one:

`Good Pen`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqBmWK?editors=1100

I can't seem to understand why the `Yes` and `No` buttons work for the "`Good Pen`", and not for the "`Bad Pen`", they are basically the same code?

Comment: Same code? There is no code in the bad one!

Comment: Add JS code of `good pen` to the `bad pen`.

Comment: The "good code" has a reference to jquery.... the "bad" one does not. It was just setup incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check in "settings" and then go to the javascript tab you will see the difference. The first one is missing jquery it should have:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js